# How can I prove this identity for the bessel function?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, bessel-functions

$$\int z^{l+1}J_m(z)dz=z^{l+1}J_{m+1}(z)+(l-m)z^lJ_m(z)-(l^2-m^2)\int z^{l-1}J_m(z)dz$$
Where $J_m$ is a Bessel function of the $mth$ kind.
I know it is integration by parts but I am not sure exactly what they are setting there $u$s and $v$s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an application of the [formula  DLMF 10.6.6](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.6) for the derivative of ordinary Bessel functions. In your special case it states:
$$\frac{d}{dz}\left(z^\nu J_\nu(z)\right) = z^\nu J_{\nu -1}(z).$$

I would also point out that $J_m(z)$ is not a Bessel function of the $m$-th kind, but a Bessel function of the first kind of order $m$. The [Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.2) offers more information about them.

Comment: hmmm... but that doesn't explain where the $(l-m)$ comes from... just raises more questions then answers. I see it for the first term not for the 2nd and 3rd ones

Comment: The $l-m$ comes from $$\frac{d}{dz}\left(z^{l+1}J_{m+1}(z)\right) = \frac{d}{dz}\left(z^{l-m}\cdot\left(z^{m+1}J_{m+1}(z)\right) \right),$$ where you derivate the two terms separately. I don't understand your last comment, but what you actually have to show is $$\frac{d}{dz} \left(z^{l+1}J_m(z) + (l^2-m^2)z^{l-1}J_m(z)\right) =  z^{l+1}J_{m+1}(z)  + (l-m)z^lJ_m(z).$$

Is it clear now?

Comment: The notation is really killing me... I really want to compute this integral $$\int_0^1 y^3 J_0(\lambda y)=\dfrac{y^3J_1(\lambda y)}{\lambda} - \dfrac{2}{\lambda} \int_0^1y^2 J_1(\lambda y)$$ I'm doing it by parts by letting $u=y^2$ $dv = y J_0(\lambda y)$

Comment: The last term ends up being $\dfrac{2}{\lambda^2} y^2 J_2(\lambda y)$ but that doesn't give me anything in terms of $J_1$ and $J_0$ which is what I want.

Comment: Dear Adam, there seems to be multiple questions floating around. 1) Are you fine with the proof of the identity of the main question? 2) Do you now want to solve the integral of your last comment in terms of elementary functions? 3) The integral $$ \int_0^1 y^3 J_0(\lambda y) dy $$ is a special case of formula 10.22.10 of the DLMF. Please let me know what the precise problem is, and also consider asking a new question if the older is answered for the sake of clarity. Thanks!